# tailing the latest stable ruby version in a rails application build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

when developing a rails application, it's possible to "hard code" the recommended ruby version by editing a ".ruby-version" file or
adding a line to the Gemfile.

```
# .ruby-version
2.5.1

# Gemfile
ruby '2.5.1'
```

My problem with this is. after an year has passed, the latest stable
ruby version might be 2.5.9, but my application is still on the old
version. I would like to know if it's possible to indicate, hey
use whatever the latest stable version of ruby is at given point in
time.

Comment: If it's a minor release, moving to higher version should not be an issue with related gems but in case of higher version, compatibility should be checked.

Comment: generally the app test suite fails, and and if tests fail nightly deployment will get halt. thats not an issue

Comment: Why do you even pin the version a current stable version when you do not care at all?

Comment: I just don't want to edit the application every time the ruby core team releases a new latest stable v

Comment: like for example, my google chrome is somehow always on the latest stable version, I don't have to do a thing

Comment: wouldn't `ruby '~> 2.5.1'` in Gemfile accomplish that?

Comment: perhaps elaborate the meaning of tilde in this context as an answer ...

Comment: It’s also important to know that if you specify a major version only, like this:'~> 2', It will only use the latest version from the 2.x series – so 2.3.0 – and not 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could use some of this bundler rules extracted from: https://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/updating_gems.html

In short for Gemfile you would write `gem 'rails'` without number and one more thing is to create some cron job to run one of these bundler commands below periodically one or two time per year to check is there any new stable version.

**Updating a Gem Without Modifying the Gemfile** 
Sometimes, you want to update a dependency without modifying the Gemfile. For example, you might want to update to the latest version of rack-cache. ***Because you did not declare a specific version of rack-cache in the Gemfile, you might want to periodically get the latest version of rack-cache.*** To do this, you want to use the bundle update command:

**$ bundle update rack-cache**
This command will update rack-cache and its dependencies to the latest version allowed by the Gemfile (in this case, the latest version available). It will not modify any other dependencies.

It will, however, update dependencies of other gems if necessary. For instance, if the latest version of rack-cache specifies a dependency on rack >= 1.2.2, bundler will update rack to 1.2.2 even though you have not asked bundler to update rack. If bundler needs to update a gem that another gem depends on, it will let you know after the update has completed.

**If you want to update every gem in the Gemfile to the latest possible versions, run:**

**$ bundle update**
This will resolve dependencies from scratch, ignoring the Gemfile.lock. If you do this, keep git reset --hard and your test suite in your back pocket. Resolving all dependencies from scratch can have surprising results, especially if a number of the third-party packages you depend on have released new versions since you last did a full update.